# WPF Custom ChartLine Performance Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, charts, linechart

We've developed a simple WPF UserControl which is a ChartLine that is usually supposed to display 512 values in a range of -100 to 100.
The chart works, however, the chart needs to have its values cleared and updated every 1 second and it is taking over a second (1.4~~seconds) to simply render all of its values.
After this frustrated attempt, I tried to use old DynamicDataDisplay (D3) from Microsoft which is supposed to be faster, but the performance impact was quite the same, also taking more than a second to update the 512 values on the screen.

Below is my code, I do believe there may be some caching technique, lower bitmap resolution or something to help achieve my goal.

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="IHM.OsciloscopeGraphic"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:IHM"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="740" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">
<Grid x:Name="gdMain">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:OsciloscopeGraphic}}, Path=TitleGreen}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="10, 0" FontSize="18" Width="115" Background="Green"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:OsciloscopeGraphic}}, Path=TitleLightBlue}" FontSize="18" Margin="10, 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="LightBlue" Grid.Column="1" Width="115"/>

    <Grid Name="gdChartArea" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="30, 10, 10, 30"/>
        <Canvas x:Name="cnvChart" Margin="30, 10, 10, 30">
        <Canvas.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#4C000080" Offset="1"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#4C7F7FFF"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Canvas.Background>
    </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

C# Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace IHM
{
    public partial class OsciloscopeGraphic : UserControl
    {
        #region Properties
        /// <summary>
        /// If steps Lines are 0, will divide the grid equally by the number in lines grid
        /// </summary>
        public int LinesGrid { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// If steps Columns are 0, will divide the grid equally by the number in lines grid
        /// </summary>
        public int ColumnsGrid { get; set; }

        public int StepsLines { get; set; }
        public int StepsColumns { get; set; }

        public int MaxHorizontal { get; set; }

        public int MaxVertical { get; set; }

        public int MinHorizontal { get; set; }
        public int MinVertical { get; set; }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleGreenProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TitleGreen", typeof(string), typeof(BarGraphicSplitted), new UIPropertyMetadata("TRS"));

        [Bindable(true)]
        public string TitleGreen
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TitleGreenProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TitleGreenProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleLightBlueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TitleLightBlue", typeof(string), typeof(BarGraphicSplitted), new UIPropertyMetadata("FRT"));

        [Bindable(true)]
        public string TitleLightBlue
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TitleLightBlueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TitleLightBlueProperty, value); }
        }
        #endregion Properties

        #region Local Fields/Variables

        private bool initialized = false;

        private int Quantidade
        {
            get { return (Math.Abs(this.MaxHorizontal - this.MinHorizontal) + 1); }
        }
        #endregion Local Fields/Variables

        public OsciloscopeGraphic()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.MaxHorizontal = 255;
            this.MinHorizontal = 0;
            this.MaxVertical = 100;
            this.MinVertical = -100;
            this.LinesGrid = 0;
            this.ColumnsGrid = 0;

            this.StepsColumns = 10;
            this.StepsLines = 10;
        }

        #region Private Local/Methods

        private Line CreateGridLine()
        {
            Line lm = new Line();
            lm.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
            lm.StrokeThickness = 1;
            lm.StrokeDashArray = new DoubleCollection() { 1, 4 };
            lm.SetValue(RenderOptions.EdgeModeProperty, EdgeMode.Aliased);

            return lm;
        }

        private Line CreateHorizontalGridLine(Point start, double length)
        {
            Line ln = CreateGridLine();
            //It has the same value because the line will be a vertical line
            ln.X1 = start.X;
            ln.X2 = start.X + length;
            ln.Y1 = start.Y;
            ln.Y2 = start.Y;

            return ln;
        }

        private Line CreateHorizontalScaleLine(Point start)
        {
            Line l = CreateScaleLine();
            l.X1 = start.X;
            l.X2 = start.X - 5;
            l.Y1 = start.Y;
            l.Y2 = start.Y;

            return l;
        }

        private Line CreateScaleLine()
        {
            Line l = new Line();
            l.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
            l.SetValue(RenderOptions.EdgeModeProperty, EdgeMode.Aliased);

            return l;
        }

        private Line CreateVerticalGridLine(Point start, double length)
        {
            Line ln = CreateGridLine();
            //It has the same value because the line will be a vertical line
            ln.X1 = start.X;
            ln.X2 = start.X;
            ln.Y1 = start.Y;
            ln.Y2 = start.Y + length;
            return ln;
        }
        private Line CreateVerticalScaleLine(Point start)
        {
            Line l = CreateScaleLine();
            l.X1 = start.X;
            l.X2 = start.X;
            l.Y1 = start.Y;
            l.Y2 = start.Y + 5;
            return l;
        }

        private void DrawGrid(Grid grid, Canvas chart)
        {
            bool makeBySteps = true;
            if ((this.StepsColumns == 0) || (this.StepsLines == 0))
            {
                makeBySteps = false;
                if ((this.LinesGrid == 0) || (this.ColumnsGrid == 0))
                    throw new DivideByZeroException();
            }

            //get canvas absolute position
            var getPos = chart.TransformToVisual(grid);
            Point XYpos = getPos.Transform(new Point(0, 0));

            //draw the lines
            double actualWidth = (chart.ActualWidth);
            double initialPosition = (XYpos.X + 1);
            double length = this.MaxHorizontal - this.MinHorizontal + 1;
            double stepLegend = (makeBySteps) ? this.StepsColumns : length / Convert.ToDouble(this.ColumnsGrid);
            int counter = (makeBySteps) ? ((int)length) / this.StepsColumns : this.ColumnsGrid;
            double step = (makeBySteps) ? (actualWidth / length) * this.StepsColumns : (actualWidth / this.ColumnsGrid);
            length = Math.Abs(length);
            double remainder = 0d;


            for (int i = 0; i <= counter; i++)
            {
                //vertical gridlines
                double steps = i * step;
                Point start = new Point(initialPosition + steps, XYpos.Y);
                Line Lm = CreateVerticalGridLine(start, chart.ActualHeight);
                grid.Children.Add(Lm);

                //vertical scale lines
                Point startScale = new Point(initialPosition + steps, XYpos.Y + chart.ActualHeight);
                Line LineScale = CreateVerticalScaleLine(startScale);
                grid.Children.Add(LineScale);


                //bottom labels
                Label lb = new Label();
                lb.Width = 20;
                lb.Height = 20;
                lb.Padding = new Thickness(0);
                lb.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                lb.ClipToBounds = false;
                //this garantes that it will consider the reminder of divisions
                double numero = this.MinHorizontal + (i * stepLegend);
                remainder += numero - Math.Round(numero);
                numero = Math.Round(numero);
                if (remainder > 1)
                {
                    remainder -= 1;
                    numero += 1;
                }
                else if (remainder < -1)
                {
                    remainder += 1;
                    numero -= 1;
                }
                lb.Content = numero;
                grid.Children.Add(lb);
                lb.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                lb.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                //TODO: big coment explaining in details the line bellow
                lb.Margin = new Thickness((XYpos.X - 10) + steps, XYpos.Y + chart.ActualHeight + 5, 0, 0);
            }

            initialPosition = XYpos.Y;
            double actualHeight = (chart.ActualHeight);
            length = this.MaxVertical - this.MinVertical + 1;
            stepLegend = (makeBySteps) ? this.StepsLines : length / Convert.ToDouble(this.LinesGrid);
            counter = (makeBySteps) ? ((int)length) / this.StepsLines : this.LinesGrid;
            step = (makeBySteps) ? (actualHeight / length) * this.StepsLines : (actualHeight / this.LinesGrid);
            //initialPosition = (makeBySteps) ? initialPosition + ((actualHeight / length) * (length % this.StepsLines)) : initialPosition;
            length = Math.Abs(length);
            remainder = 0d;

            for (int i = 0; i <= counter; i++)
            {
                double steps = i * step;
                Point start = new Point(XYpos.X, actualHeight + initialPosition - steps);
                //horizontal gridlines
                Line lm = CreateHorizontalGridLine(start, actualWidth);
                grid.Children.Add(lm);
                //horizontal scale lines
                Line l = CreateHorizontalScaleLine(start);
                grid.Children.Add(l);
                //side labels
                Label lb = new Label();
                lb.Width = 30;
                lb.Height = 20;
                lb.HorizontalContentAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Right;
                lb.Padding = new Thickness(0);
                lb.VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                lb.ClipToBounds = false;
                //this garantes that it will consider the reminder of divisions
                double numero = this.MinVertical + (i * stepLegend);
                remainder += numero - Math.Round(numero);
                numero = Math.Round(numero);
                if (remainder > 1)
                {
                    remainder -= 1;
                    numero += 1;
                }
                else if (remainder < -1)
                {
                    remainder += 1;
                    numero -= 1;
                }
                lb.Content = numero;

                grid.Children.Add(lb);
                lb.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                lb.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                //TODO: big coment explaining in details the line bellow
                lb.Margin = new Thickness(XYpos.X - 37, start.Y - 10, 0, 0);
            }
        }


        private void DrawGrid()
        {
            this.DrawGrid(gdChartArea, cnvChart);
        }

        private void DrawLine(List<int> p_values, SolidColorBrush cor)
        {
            Polyline cl = new Polyline();
            cl.Stroke = cor;
            cl.StrokeThickness = 2;
            cl.StrokeLineJoin = PenLineJoin.Round;
            //cl.SetValue(RenderOptions.EdgeModeProperty, EdgeMode.Aliased);
            double stepHorizontal = cnvChart.ActualWidth / ((this.MaxHorizontal - this.MinHorizontal) + 1);
            double stepVertical = cnvChart.ActualHeight / ((this.MaxVertical - this.MinVertical) + 1);

            for (int i = 0; i < p_values.Count; i++)
            {
                int val = p_values[i];
                double x = (stepHorizontal * i);
                double y = cnvChart.ActualHeight - ((val - this.MinVertical) * stepVertical);

                cl.Points.Add(new Point(x, y));
            }

            cnvChart.Children.Add(cl);
        }

        private void DrawLineGreen(List<int> p_values)
        {
            DrawLine(p_values, Brushes.Green);
        }

        private void DrawLineLightBlue(List<int> p_values)
        {
            DrawLine(p_values, Brushes.LightBlue);
        }

        private List<int> GetRandomValues()
        {
            int quantidade = this.Quantidade;
            List<int> lsValues = new List<int>(quantidade);
            int seed = 0;
            long ticks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            while (ticks > int.MaxValue)
            {
                ticks -= int.MaxValue;
            }
            seed = Convert.ToInt32(ticks);
            Random ran = new Random(seed);

            for (int i = 0; i < quantidade; i++)
            {
                int randomValue = ran.Next(this.MinVertical, this.MaxVertical);
                lsValues.Add(randomValue);
            }

            return lsValues;
        }

        #endregion Private Local/Methods

        #region Public Methods

        public void Clear()
        {
            this.cnvChart.Children.Clear();
        }

        public void UpdateGraphValues()
        {
            UpdateGraphValues(GetRandomValues(), GetRandomValues());
        }

        public void UpdateGraphValues(List<int> p_frontValues, List<int> p_backValues)
        {
            //Clear current graphic values.
            Clear();

            DrawLineGreen(p_frontValues);
            DrawLineLightBlue(p_backValues);
        }

        #endregion Public Methods

        #region Window Events

        private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!initialized)
            {
                DrawGrid();
                UpdateGraphValues();
                initialized = true;
            }
        }

        #endregion Window Events
    }
}
```

To test the graph in the conditions I'd like you can simply instantiate`

```
    private OsciloscopeGraphic graphicOscNormal = new OsciloscopeGraphic() 
    {
        MinHorizontal = 0,
        MaxHorizontal = 255,
        MinVertical = -100,
        MaxVertical = 100
    };
```

and inside a timer you may call `` `graphicOscNormal.UpdateGraphValues() `` ` which will furfill the graphic with random values for testing purposes.
Later these values will come from serial port which is already implemented.

NOTE: I've also tried to replace the high level PolyLine for DrawingVisual and DrawingContext.DrawLine, BUT the performance has NOT changed!

NOTE2: I'm using C#/WPF and .NET 4.0 (VS 2010).

Thanks in advanced, Luís.

Comment: Have you tried OxyPlot. oxyplot.codeplex.com

Comment: Performance problems must be profiled - which part is slow?  Suggest DotTrace or similar, don't shoot in the dark.

Comment: OxyPlot seems great... but it still isn't the answer, I've tested it and it takes about 800ms to render. It's an improvement already compared to my 1.3~~1.4 secs.
I'll try to use some profiling tool to check the problem in a deeper level.

Comment: I would have a closer look at D3 - in particular the `LineGraph`.  For only 256 points this should be very fast.  For your purposes you could make a custom Canvas and implement the drawing by overriding `OnRender`.  D3 should give you some ideas.

Comment: I'm sorry, I tested OxyPlot with 256 values, and indeed my graphic uses 2 lists(lines) of 256 values each, resulting in 512 values (I've updated my post saying that it is 512 instead of 256 values).
Using OxyPlot Model example (Which is the fastest accordingly to them) and providing my 512 values, the updating time takes place at 1.5 seconds which is even a bit slower than my own custom graphic control.
I did use D3 LineGraph and the performance was poor, I'll give it another shot but it has no documentation at all, don't know what else I could try there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (biggest) problem is your random number generator - it is extremely inefficient.  Try :

```
    private Random ran = new Random(0);
    private List<int> GetRandomValues()
    {
        int quantidade = this.Quantidade;
        List<int> lsValues = new List<int>(quantidade);

        for (int i = 0; i < quantidade; i++)
        {
            int randomValue = ran.Next(this.MinVertical, this.MaxVertical);
            lsValues.Add(randomValue);
        }

        return lsValues;
    }
```

When optimizing, it pays to profile.

If you want really, *really* fast rendering then you almost have to go back to GDI.  For example - update your `Canvas` (cnvChart) to use this `FastCanvas` :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    class FastCanvas : Canvas
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CreateFileMapping(IntPtr hFile,
                                                       IntPtr lpFileMappingAttributes,
                                                       uint flProtect,
                                                       uint dwMaximumSizeHigh,
                                                       uint dwMaximumSizeLow,
                                                       string lpName);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr MapViewOfFile(IntPtr hFileMappingObject,
                                                   uint dwDesiredAccess,
                                                   uint dwFileOffsetHigh,
                                                   uint dwFileOffsetLow,
                                                   uint dwNumberOfBytesToMap);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool UnmapViewOfFile(IntPtr lbBaseAddress);


        protected System.Drawing.Graphics GDIGraphics;
        protected InteropBitmap interopBitmap = null;
        protected InteropBitmap buffBitmap = null;

        private const uint FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS = 0xF001F;
        private const uint PAGE_READWRITE = 0x04;

        private int bpp = PixelFormats.Bgra32.BitsPerPixel / 8;
        protected IntPtr MapViewPointer;

        public struct ScopeLine
        {
            public SolidColorBrush lineBrush;
            public List<Point> linePoints;
        }

        public List<ScopeLine> Lines = new List<ScopeLine>();

        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
        {
            base.OnRender(dc);
            if (Lines.Count() > 0)
            {              
                    ImageSource drIs = null;

                    if (interopBitmap == null)
                    {
                        uint byteCount = (uint)((int)this.ActualWidth * (int)this.ActualHeight * bpp);

                        var fileMappingPointer = CreateFileMapping(new IntPtr(-1), IntPtr.Zero, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, byteCount, null);
                        this.MapViewPointer = MapViewOfFile(fileMappingPointer, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, byteCount);
                        PixelFormat format = PixelFormats.Bgra32;
                        var stride = (int)((int)this.ActualWidth * format.BitsPerPixel / 8);
                        this.interopBitmap = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromMemorySection(fileMappingPointer,
                                                                                         (int)this.ActualWidth,
                                                                                         (int)this.ActualHeight,
                                                                                         format,
                                                                                         stride,
                                                                                         0) as InteropBitmap;

                        this.GDIGraphics = GetGdiGraphics(MapViewPointer);
                    }

                    GDIGraphics.FillRectangle(System.Drawing.Brushes.Transparent,
                                                    new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0,
                                                    (int)this.ActualWidth,
                                                    (int)this.ActualHeight));

                    foreach (ScopeLine dLine in Lines)
                    {
                        var pointCount = dLine.linePoints.Count();
                        Color lpColour;
                        lpColour = dLine.lineBrush.Color;
                        System.Drawing.Color lp2Colour;
                        lp2Colour = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(lpColour.A,
                                                                  lpColour.R,
                                                                  lpColour.G,
                                                                  lpColour.B);


                        System.Drawing.Pen lpPen = new System.Drawing.Pen(lp2Colour, 1.5f);
                        System.Drawing.PointF newPoint = new System.Drawing.PointF((float)dLine.linePoints[0].X,
                                                                                   (float)dLine.linePoints[0].Y);


                        for (int i = 0; i < pointCount - 1; i++)
                        {
                            System.Drawing.PointF newPoint1 = new System.Drawing.PointF((float)dLine.linePoints[i + 1].X,
                                                                                            (float)dLine.linePoints[i + 1].Y);
                            GDIGraphics.DrawLine(lpPen, newPoint, newPoint1);
                            newPoint = newPoint1;
                        }

                    }

                    var bmpsrc = interopBitmap.GetAsFrozen();
                    if (bmpsrc == null || bmpsrc.CheckAccess())
                    {
                        drIs = (System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource)bmpsrc;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Debug.WriteLine("No access to TheImage");
                    }                                    

                    dc.DrawImage(drIs, new Rect(this.RenderSize));
            }
        }

        private System.Drawing.Graphics GetGdiGraphics(IntPtr mapViewPointer)
        {
            System.Drawing.Graphics gdiGraphics;
            System.Drawing.Bitmap gdiBitmap;
            gdiBitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap((int)this.ActualWidth,
                                                  (int)this.ActualHeight,
                                                  (int)this.ActualWidth * bpp,
                                                  System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb,
                                                  mapViewPointer);

            gdiGraphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(gdiBitmap);
            gdiGraphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
            gdiGraphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;
            gdiGraphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighSpeed;

            return gdiGraphics;
        }
    }
}
```

and change your `DrawLine` as :

```
    private void DrawLine(List<int> p_values, SolidColorBrush cor)
    {            
        double stepHorizontal = cnvChart.ActualWidth / ((this.MaxHorizontal - this.MinHorizontal) + 1);
        double stepVertical = cnvChart.ActualHeight / ((this.MaxVertical - this.MinVertical) + 1);

        List<Point> pts = new List<Point>();

        for (int i = 0; i < p_values.Count; i++)
        {
            int val = p_values[i];
            double x = (stepHorizontal * i);
            double y = cnvChart.ActualHeight - ((val - this.MinVertical) * stepVertical);
            pts.Add(new Point(x,y));                       
        }

        FastCanvas.ScopeLine newLine;
        newLine.lineBrush = cor;
        newLine.linePoints = pts;

        cnvChart.Lines.Add(newLine);            
    }
```

and `UpdateValues` to :

```
    public void UpdateGraphValues(List<int> p_frontValues, List<int> p_backValues)
    {            
        cnvChart.Lines.Clear();
        DrawLineGreen(p_frontValues);
        DrawLineLightBlue(p_backValues);
        cnvChart.InvalidateVisual();
    }
```

Using GDI like this the same graph can update in real time (easily > 30fps for 512 points) as compared to about 5-7fps using WPF rendering.

Comment: You were right, such a silly method was responsible for 90% of the performance impact in the code. Along with correcting the GetRandomValues method and using some caching, freezable I've managed to increase performance tremendously.
Just to complete the answer, along with your answer: this code also helped a lot http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ec0c2742-9ddc-4951-b6e7-41e93814ce1f/polyline-drawing-optimization-in-wpf

Answer (score 1):

First thing you can do in order to improve performance is replacing all Labels with TextBlocks. TextBlocks are drawn much faster! Freeze all freezables (custom Brushes for example) as is described [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509.aspx). Maybe [THIS](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ec0c2742-9ddc-4951-b6e7-41e93814ce1f/polyline-drawing-optimization-in-wpf), [THIS](http://khason.net/blog/how-to-high-performance-graphics-in-wpf/) and [THIS](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/486955/WPFpluschartplusdrawingplusoptimization) can help too, these are threads about Polyline optimization. I hope i helped:)

Comment: Labels do not have such a BIG impact on performance, and my code does not draw several labels, it doesn't even draw twice, so that has no effect at all. Freeze states indeed does, and the article you posted http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ec0c2742-9ddc-4951-b6e7-41e93814ce1f/polyline-drawing-optimization-in-wpf was EXTREMELY helpful. I'm using several hints and cache from this code. The performance has improved a lot.
Thanks for the reply!